# Best way to implement websockets in Polymer web app

Tags: javascript, websocket, polymer

I am currently developping a single view application in Polymer/js.

Some of my custom-elements will need to be connected to the server via websocket, to get refreshed. 
After some search on the internet I saw that there are quite a few existing websocket-elements. Is it a good practice?

I am new to Polymer and web development, and for me the best way would be to have a WebSocket singleton object or something lile that, and then all the elements in need would reuse it. Here it's impossible, and I don't know how to implement this the right way. Any feedback appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer seems to be a wrapper for specific Javascript and html features related to [WebComponents](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebComponents/).

I think a regular javascript Websocket would work perfectly, allowing you to access Polymer API within it's callbacks.

Comment: Ok, for now this was my plan, but I still wonder is there is any Polymer-way. Thanks Myst